# why is my router not working in react - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anyone tell me why my router is not working, I didn’t do anything to complicated with my app its one one page and I tried to add a router in app.js that has a link to my home page and every time i add router everything disappears from my app its just a white screen.

```
app.js 
 
import "aos/dist/aos.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome to React Router!</h1>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
Home.js

import React from 'react'

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>Home</div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

```
index.js

import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";


ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: View the browser console (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J`) and include what errors you see.

Comment: @code [Warning] Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page. (bundle.js, line 35220)

Comment: @code Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
Routes@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35447:12
div
div
App
Router@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35384:12
BrowserRouter@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34861:11

Comment: Is your file `app.js` or `App.js`? In the JS you imported it with the uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Switch instead of Routes and you also don't have to use triangular brackets in element

```js
import Home from './components/Home';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router';

<Switch>
  <Route path="/" element={Home} />       
</Switch>
```

Comment: I don't think switch works with react 6 I got an error when I tried it

Comment: https://codepen.io/NapalmDeath/pen/oNeOxjq okay then try to look at this method of implementation

Comment: That's for rr v4.

Comment: You're using a hash router in your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all path begin with / go to your home page, you can change like this: <Route path="/*" element={} />

Comment: If the OP wanted everything to go to the home page, they should not be using React Router.